# Page Refresh Causing Postback - Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form inside a Usercontrol, & calling this from a page say index.aspx. 
After submitting the form and clicking refresh, it again causes postback. 
So, I tried to maintain a flag in a viewstate as '1' after data saved and '0' when it is initial page load.

But why does the viewstate change its value to 0 with refresh.
How to resolve this.

**MyForm.ascx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(!IsPostBack){
        ViewState["DataSaved"] = 0;
    }
}

protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (Page.IsValid && Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["DataSaved"]) == 0){
        //save data;
        ViewState["DataSaved"] = 1;
    } else{
        ViewState["DataSaved"] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you submit the form and then click refresh?  Of course refresh will reset everything that's what it does.

Comment: yup @bowlturner. The clue is in the name :)

Comment: Look up "Post/Redirect/Get" pattern

Answer (score 2):

On refresh the page is reverted as it was initially (you came to this page via GET request). 
So Viewstate is returned to its initial state and all changes made to it are lost. This is normal behavior. The behavior you expect is more like a session, so you might try using a session - it will maintain its state between requests.

Look at this for general understanding of page life cycle in .net:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

And this for explanation of Viewstate:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Both will be very helpful for you!
Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To make it simple, ViewState is saving inside user machine, and Session is saving inside server machine (access by cookies).
ViewState will be refresh whenever page  `IsPostBack` or `!IsPostBack`
Session, however, will not.

In your case, i think you should use Session, instead of ViewState.

To understand more, you can go through [ASP.NET Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227435(v=vs.100).aspx). It's always good to learn from basic

Answer (score -2):

Use a Session instead of the ViewState.

Comment: His problem is related to a lack of understanding of the page life cycle. Putting values into the Session isn't the right approach here.